# Elasticsearch geo query with aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I have an elasticsearch index containing user locations. 
I need to perform aggregate query with geo bounding box using geohash grid, and for buckets that have documents count less than some value, i need to return all documents.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any relevant information about the index which you have created and the user locations.

I am considering the below data:

**index Def**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Sample Doc**

```
POST _bulk

{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"location":"52.37408,4.912350","name":"The golden dragon"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"location":"52.369219,4.901618","name":"Burger King"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"location":"52.371667,4.914722","name":"Wendys"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"location":"51.222900,4.405200","name":"Taco Bell"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"location":"48.861111,2.336389","name":"McDonalds"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"location":"48.860000,2.327000","name":"KFC"}
```

**According to your question:**

> When requesting detailed buckets a filter like `geo_bounding_box`
>   should be applied to narrow the subject area

To know more about this, you can refer to this [official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html)

- Now, in  order to filter data based on `doc_count` with aggregations, we can use [bucket_selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) pipeline aggregation.

From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html)

> Pipeline aggregations work on the outputs produced from other
>   aggregations rather than from document sets, adding information to the
>   output tree.

So, the amount of work that need to be done to calculate doc_count will be the same.

**Query**

```
    {
  "aggs": {
    "location": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
          "location": {
            "top_left": {
              "lat": 52.5225,
              "lon": 4.5552
            },
            "bottom_right": {
              "lat": 52.2291,
              "lon": 5.2322
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "around_amsterdam": {
          "geohash_grid": {
            "field": "location",
            "precision": 8
          },
          "aggs": {
            "the_filter": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "the_doc_count": "_count"
                },
                "script": "params.the_doc_count < 2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 6,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "restaurant",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "location": "52.37408,4.912350",
          "name": "The golden dragon"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "restaurant",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "location": "52.369219,4.901618",
          "name": "Burger King"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "restaurant",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "location": "52.371667,4.914722",
          "name": "Wendys"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "restaurant",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "location": "51.222900,4.405200",
          "name": "Taco Bell"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "restaurant",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "location": "48.861111,2.336389",
          "name": "McDonalds"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "restaurant",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "location": "48.860000,2.327000",
          "name": "KFC"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "location": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "around_amsterdam": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "u173zy3j",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "u173zvfz",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "u173zt90",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It will filter out all the documents, whose count is less than 2 based on `"params.the_doc_count < 2"`

Comment: @ruffnecktsk t have you gone through my answer..is your issue resolved??

Comment: @ruffnecktsk t  did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please dont forget to upvote and accept :)